# Adding field in view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

I working on one application, and I started learning ASP.NET so I am begginer and I am trying to add one field in view. 
So, I have Firstname,Address, ZIP, State etc and I want for every medical provider add his|her speciality. I create a table and make connection beatween two table. 
When I add SPeciality, it doesnt show up in view. I have no idea where I made mistake.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYwOg.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM8Rg.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDY2q.jpg

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
$.getJSON("/NfDocuments/MedicalInput", { id: id },
   function (data) {
      $('#medInput').empty();
       $.each(data, function () {
           // $("#medInput").append("'" + this.Id + "'");
           //console.log(this.Id);
           var medInput = document.getElementById("medInput");
           medInput.value = this.Firstname + ' - ' + this.Zip + ' ' + this.Address1 + ',' + this.City + ', ' + this.State + ' - ' + this.Mobile;
       });
   });
```

Any suggestion, comment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
medInput.value =   this.Firstname + ' - ' 
                 + this.Zip + ' ' 
                 + this.Address1 + ',' 
                 + this.City + ', ' 
                 + this.State + ' - ' 
                 + this.Mobile;
```

You need to append `this.SpecialityName` (or whatever you have it named as when returned to the view) to `medInput.Value`:

```
medInput.value =   this.Firstname + ' - ' 
                 + this.Zip + ' ' 
                 + this.Address1 + ',' 
                 + this.City + ', ' 
                 + this.State + ' - ' 
                 + this.Mobile + ' - '
                 + this.SpecialityName;
```

I'm assuming the id of each speciality is `this.TypeId` and that you have already mapped `TypeId` to some kind of `SpecialityName` before sending the object back to the view.

Comment: Yes, the specaility is this.TypeId and its alredy mapped TypeId. But I am not so sure will I get the ID of medical provider or string of SpecialityName ?

Comment: `TypeId` will return `TypeId`, you can't automagically convert it to a `SpecialityName`. How you implement this is up to you. Personally, I'd just return an additional column from the database containing the speciality name (the information is already on the first table if I understand the image correctly)

Comment: Thanks, Yes, the information is on the first table which is connect by Id to another one

Comment: So you `JOIN` on `Id` - you can then just also select `Name AS 'SpecialityName'` from that join.

Comment: Thank you @trashr0x